# Embed XML in HTML (Firefox compatible)

Tags: html, xml, xslt, embed

I have an XML file (dynamically created) and an XSL style sheet; if I open the XML file within Firefox, I get a nice table of output.

However, I want to render this data *within* an HTML page. I've tried using:

HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <xml src="test_data.xml">
    </xml>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I can't get anything to render. Both my XML file and my XSL file are in the same directory.

I've tried removing `<html>` and `<body>` from my XSL output, but still get no results.

Online I've read that some methods differ for IE and Firefox; how can I render an XML file within an HTML page in Firefox?

---

XML file (**test_data.xml**):

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report_proteins.xsl"?>
<group_list>
    <protein_group>
        <protein name="A_1" />
        <protein name="A_2" />
    </protein_group>
    <protein_group>
        <protein name="B_1" />
    </protein_group>
    <protein_group>
        <protein name="C_1" />
        <protein name="C_2" />
        <protein name="C_3" />
    </protein_group>
</group_list>
```

XSL file (**report_proteins.xsl**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>MAP proteins</h2>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#E7FFCC">Group number</th>
        <th bgcolor="#D2FBFF">Proteins</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="group_list/protein_group">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:number />
          </td>
          <td>
          <xsl:for-each select="protein">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such `xml` node in HTML, so that is the reason why it doesn't work. You don't need the HTML file at all. Your XSLT sheet generates a full XHTML document, and the browser should be able to render that as it is if you open the XML find in the browser.

You should add the XHTML namespace to the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: I believe that @Oliver was asking how to render the result of the transform within other html, not how to render the transformed xml as the entire html page.

Comment: With the html elements added to the XSLT sheet, Oliver will get exactly what he wants. I think I did adress the issue about not being able to include the result using an `xml` element.

Comment: It was a little strange because I wanted to transform the XML template with Django first, and then deliver it, but I just rendered from the XSLT sheet within python and delivered the HTML result. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use iframe element.

```
<iframe src="test_data.xml"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap it inside an iframe tag instead of an xml tag:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="test_data.xml"></iframe>
    </xml>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, no, this is not supported by web browsers.

You should probably do your transform on the server, and push html to the browser.

I don't recommend it, but if you must do this client-side, have a look at 
http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/ which supposedly implements xslt in javascript (I've never been foolish enough to try it, so I don't know if it actually works).

Comment: Both Firefox and IE support XSLT.