# How to search XML document info with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am making an account system and at the moment I am writing the code for a test to see if a (username, email, ext) is registered. But to do this I need Javascript to read the XML docs with the info. How do you get Javascript to read the XML docs? Here is an example XML doc.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <user>
        <firstName>Bob</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <email>bob.smith@fakeEmail.com</email>
        <username>BobS.</username>
        <password>pizza</password>
    </user>
```

Comment: Please provide a little more context. For example: Is this a web page, are the documents embedded in the HTML, are they separate files/resources?  Are you going to use AJAX to request them when the page loads?  Are you using anything like jQuery?

Comment: @TedJohnson It is in a webpage. I haven't thought of using AJAX.

Comment: Everybody using your account system is allowed to download these information about all users? I guess you will have to do it serverside. However, the answer to your question is Ajax, and then just use the DOM of the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two real steps here.  I will use jquery for simplicity sake.

1.Get the XML resource:

AJAX: var xmlDoc = $.get('XMLURL').promise(function (xmlData){
  //do step two
});

Embedded in HTML like in this question: [Embedding XML in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html)

2.Once you have the DOM:

Use jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Or do it yourself: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp