# Maximum values allowed inbetween <div> tags in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, svg, responsive-images

I have a web page that is using a SVG coordinates on the asp.net framework.

By trial an error, if i take out most of the tags i recieve no error.   But if all the tags are in i get the following error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS8095: Length of String constant exceeds current memory limit. Try splitting the string into multiple constants.
Line 195:        private global::System.Web.UI.LiteralControl              @__BuildControl__control2() {
Line 196:            global::System.Web.UI.LiteralControl @__ctrl;
Line 197:            @__ctrl = new     global::System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("\r\n\r\n  \r\n<div class=\"row\">\r\n          <div class=\"col-xs-24 banner section\">\r\n        " +
Line 198:                    "<div class=\"row\">\r\n<div class=\"col-xs-24     col-sm-14 map-container\"> <!-- MICHAEL:" +
Line 199:                    " be sure to add the class \'map-container\',     this is for the tooltip location -->\r" +
```

the source code is

```
<div class="col-xs-24 col-sm-14 map-container"> <!-- MICHAEL: be sure to add the class 'map-container', this is for the tooltip location -->
        <!-- <img class="map" src="images/map.svg" width="100%"> -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             viewBox="0 230.5 613.3 331" enable-background="new 0 230.5 613.3 331" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="609.6,301.2 609.4,301.1 609.3,301.1 609.1,301 609,300.9 608.8,300.8 608.6,300.7 608.5,300.6
                608.4,300.4 608.3,300.3 608.2,300.1 608.1,299.9 608.1,299.8 608,299.6 608,299.4 608,299.2 608,299 608,298.9 608.1,298.7
                608.1,298.4 608.2,298.3 608.3,298.1 608.4,298 608.5,297.9 608.6,297.7 608.8,297.6 609,297.5 609.1,297.4 609.3,297.3
                609.4,297.3 609.6,297.2 609.8,297.2 610,297.2 610.2,297.2 610.4,297.2 610.5,297.3 610.8,297.3 610.9,297.4 611.1,297.5
                611.2,297.6 611.4,297.7 611.5,297.9 611.6,298 611.7,298.1 611.8,298.3 611.9,298.4 611.9,298.7 612,298.9 612,299 612,299.2
                612,299.4 612,299.6 611.9,299.8 611.9,299.9 611.8,300.1 611.7,300.3 611.6,300.4 611.5,300.6 611.4,300.7 611.2,300.8
                611.1,300.9 610.9,301 610.8,301.1 610.5,301.1 610.4,301.2 610.2,301.2 610,301.2 609.8,301.2     "/>
            <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="601.2,301.1 601.3,301 601.4,300.8 601.5,300.7 601.7,300.6 601.9,300.5 601.9,300.5 602.1,300.4
                602.2,300.4 602.4,300.3 602.6,300.3 602.7,300.3 602.8,300.3 602.9,300.3 603.1,300.3 603.4,300.4 603.5,300.4 603.6,300.5
                603.8,300.6 604,300.7 604.2,300.8 604.3,301 604.3,301.1 604.5,301.2 604.6,301.4 604.6,301.5 604.7,301.8 604.8,301.9
                604.8,302.1 604.8,302.4 604.8,302.5 604.8,302.7 604.7,302.9 604.6,303 604.6,303.2 604.5,303.3 604.3,303.5 604.3,303.7
                604.2,303.8 604,303.9 603.8,304 603.6,304.1 603.5,304.2 603.4,304.2 603.1,304.3 602.9,304.3 602.8,304.3 602.6,304.3
                602.4,304.3 602.2,304.2 602.1,304.2 601.9,304.1 601.7,304 601.5,303.9 601.4,303.8 601.3,303.7 601.2,303.5 601.1,303.3
                601,303.2 600.9,303 600.8,302.9 600.8,302.7 600.8,302.5 600.8,302.4 600.8,302.1 600.8,301.9 600.8,301.8 600.9,301.5 601,301.4
                601.1,301.2     "/>
```

+8000 more lines

What can i do?  I need to use the element tags because with jquery i am going to have events happening to these tags.   So i cannot point just point to the  file.  I need all the

update i got the inline polygon tags down to 1 line of 898kb, and i noticed VSBComplier.exe (something like that) take up ALL of my RAM and crash my browser.

Still have to take the svg out in comment in order to debug.

Comment: narrow it down: divide the tag soup into halves and figure out whether it is the quantity/length of content, or a certain malformed tag?
Your "error description" contains source lines and ASP runtime generated code but no error message: is there an error code or exception text?

Comment: i have done that already, if i use less code it works.  But i need all this code.  The error text was already posted in the question above.  It says im using a literalcontrol, but i am not

Comment: ASP.NET is creating a literal control, under the hood, under certain circumstances. that part of page source code you posted seems to be embedded in a `<div class="row">`  - what does that markup hierarchy look like when we go up further? is it part of a masterpage or updatepanel construction?

Comment: +1 for originality. Here, ASP.NET seems to impose a limit when there really should be none. a first idea: Circumvent it by loading the markup into an `<iframe>` and let your jquery operate on that `<iframe>`'s DOM

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html) suggests that the xml needs to be embedded in a different way. also IMO, the `<?xml version...>` is a document header and cannot occur in the middle of a html document. try to remove just this line.

Comment: that xml line with our without made no difference

Comment: There is no length limit for the content in a div tag. Title is a little misleading. Sounds like the size of the string exceeds the length of that type.

Comment: in master pages, there seems to be, in development debug mode only

Answer (score 1):

THe issue was iisexpress vs iis.exe w3p.exe.  This only happens on my local computer

in debug it gives this error.

Putting it on a production server, the error does not happen

Hopefully this thread serves a purpose.  Even though my computer has plenty of RAM and space.

Answer (score 0):

How about separating your very long string constant into several chunks and have them all in a `List<String>`

Also, consider using single-page-application approach where you make an ajax call to the web server which will directly return the SVG data and then display the SVG data using client side programming such as JQuery. This will avoid having to render things server-side in ASP.NET MVC's views.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here, by why not load the SVG via CSS?

Comment: i needed access to the dom elements of the svg later for animation of particulars