# Length of string constant exceeds current memory limit. Try splitting the string into multiple constants

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control (.ascx) file. I am dynamically loading contents of this user control & want to write it to a StringWriter.

but i am getting this error :

> Length of String constant exceeds current memory limit. Try splitting
>   the string into multiple constants

The line of code which is causing the problem is :

```
UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
```

The ascx control file size is not that big. (Almost 3 MB in size because it has some embedded images, fonts via Inline CSS).

Is there any way, I can increase the memory limit for this operation or any work around ?. 
I can think of adding the style sheet to string writer in a separate operation. but if there is some configuration to increase the memory limit I would be happy to use it.

Comment: What is the intended use of the resulting string?

Comment: want to use it for pdf generation via tuespechkin @spender

Comment: Try splitting the inline CSS into several separate inline CSS tags? Sounds like a Razor limitation as .NET strings themselves can easily accommodate a few MB of text.

Comment: @RomanStarkov it is web forms control. Razor is not involved.

Comment: A brief look at the tuespechkin repo: it looks like you can populate an `ObjectSettings` with a byte array via the `ObjectSettings.RawData` property... if you can get a stream/byte-array representation of the rendered control rather than a string, you could avoid strings altogether.

Comment: ...`RawData` expects a **UTF8** encoded byte-array

Comment: ...setting `RawData` is equivalent to setting the `ObjectSettings.HtmlText` property. Both set the same (byte-array) backing field, so by setting `RawData`, you'll avoid unnecessary conversions.

Comment: https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/blob/develop/TuesPechkin/Document/ObjectSettings.cs#LC97

Comment: @spender any ideas on loading control as a byte array.It has a listview which is databound.

Comment: Instead of loading it, how about requesting it with HttpWebRequest/WebClient/HttpClient?

Comment: In that case, using the url property in Object Settings would do the job.Thanks..

Comment: Interesting that the ASP.net can render it, but LoadControl fails...

Comment: yup i checked adding that control in a form. it works there..

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366704/maximum-values-allowed-inbetween-div-tags-in-asp-net help?