# Convert c# HtmlTextWriter page into simple asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got an old showxml web page which is written using HtmlTextWriter. I don't have enough experience working with HtmlTextWriter method and I have some problems to control it. I need xsl, xml, js, with their Ids. Because page elements control each other with their IDs. So I wanted to convert that into simple asp.net page. What is the way to do so? Below is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    String number_appl = "20170001";
    String objIntel = "marks";
    String username;
    username = User.Identity.Name;

    writer.WriteFullBeginTag("html");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("meta");
    writer.WriteAttribute("http-equiv", "Content-Type");
    writer.WriteAttribute("content", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("xml");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "template");
    writer.WriteAttribute("src", "/edit/source.aspx?objIntel=" + objIntel + "&filename=template.xml&un=");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("xml");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("xml");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "data");
    writer.WriteAttribute("src", "/edit/source.aspx?objIntel=DataBase\\" + objIntel + "&filename=\\xmls\\" + number_appl + ".xml&un=" + username);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("xml");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("xml");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "style");
    writer.WriteAttribute("src", "/edit/source.aspx?objIntel=" + objIntel + "&filename=b7b.xsl&un=" + username);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("xml");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("xml");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "xmlerror");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteBeginTag("XMLDATA");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("XMLDATA");
    writer.WriteEndTag("xml");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("LINK");
    writer.WriteAttribute("REL", "STYLESHEET");
    writer.WriteAttribute("HREF", "/edit/styles.css");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("LINK");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("script");
    writer.WriteAttribute("language", "JScript");
    writer.WriteAttribute("src", "/edit/source.aspx?objIntel=" + objIntel + "&filename=showxml.js");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("script");
    writer.WriteLine();
    writer.WriteBeginTag("TITLE");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.Write(number_appl);
    writer.WriteEndTag("TITLE");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("body");
    writer.WriteAttribute("alink", "#006666");
    writer.WriteAttribute("Link", "#006666");
    writer.WriteAttribute("Vlink", "#006666");
    writer.WriteAttribute("bgcolor", "#f0fff0");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("DIV");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "showResult");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("DIV");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.WriteBeginTag("FORM");
    writer.WriteAttribute("ENCTYPE=", "multipart/form-data");
    writer.WriteAttribute("action", "savexml.aspx?un=" + username);
    writer.WriteAttribute("method", "POST");

    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "FORM1");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteBeginTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteAttribute("type", "submit");
    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "Enter");
    writer.WriteAttribute("value", "Зафиксировать изменения");
    writer.WriteAttribute("onClick", "achSendDataToServer()");
    writer.WriteEndTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteBeginTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteAttribute("type", "hidden");
    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "blob");
    writer.WriteAttribute("value", "blob_xml");
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteBeginTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteAttribute("type", "hidden");
    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "appl_number");
    writer.WriteAttribute("value", number_appl);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteBeginTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteAttribute("type", "hidden");
    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "vid");
    writer.WriteAttribute("value", objIntel);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteBeginTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteAttribute("type", "hidden");
    writer.WriteAttribute("name", "un");
    writer.WriteAttribute("value", username);
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
    writer.WriteEndTag("INPUT");
    writer.WriteEndTag("FORM");
    writer.WriteLine();

    writer.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <user name=\"u_name\"> </user>");


    writer.WriteEndTag("body");
    writer.WriteLine();
    writer.WriteEndTag("html");

}

</script>
```

Comment: Could you get the output with writer.ToString() and then just build it from scratch from the output.  Tha output looks quite static to me, so it shouldnt take long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation isn't that hard to make, for instance :

```
writer.WriteBeginTag("DIV");
writer.WriteAttribute("id", "showResult");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
writer.WriteEndTag("DIV");
writer.WriteLine();
```

results in

```
<div id="showResult"></div>
```

because :

`WriteBeginTag("DIV");` writes a `<div`

Then we get `writer.WriteAttribute("id", "showResult");`

`WriteAttribute` adds an attribute with a value, in this case the attribute name is "id", and the value is "showResult"

`writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);` then writes the `>`, at then end of the open `<div` tag we had, so we then have `<div id="showResult">`

All that is left then is to close the tag, which is done with 
`writer.WriteEndTag("DIV");`.
(This adds the `</div>`)

Keeping that logic in mind, you should have no trouble translating this code to a decent aspx page.

Comment: This part is hard for me:

Comment: writer.WriteBeginTag("xml");
    writer.WriteAttribute("id", "template");

Comment: It says: Element xml is not suppoerted

Comment: the same logic still applies, only this time you need to print something to the page from aspx using a binding or something similar. it translates to something like : `<xml id="template" src="/edit/source.aspx?objIntel=<%=objIntel%>&filename=template.xml&un="></xml>`

Comment: Here's the thing ; having an `xml` tag in the middle of a `html` document is weird. i don't think it's valid either way, so if visual studio complains, that is rightfully so.

Comment: according to this post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html the best way of embedding xml in a html document is inside a `<script>` tag.