# Reading an xml file directly specifying the path, without using Ajax call

Tags: jquery, xml

Is there any way to read an XML file in to a variable using jQuery without using an AJAX call? I tried using an AJAX call but I did not get the XML file.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MyWebService.asmx/LoadXml",
  data: {},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (dataXML) {}
});
```

Comment: Firstly note that there's nothing wrong with the JS making that AJAX call. If it's not working for you check the path is correct, and check the console for errors. Yes, you could output the XML in to a `<script type="text/xmldata">` tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html. You would need to parse it manually, though.

Comment: You might be looking for something like this [Read xml using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan   I do not know this is not working for me. I even tried with direct path of the xml file instead of calling it from a web service, but still no xml data is mapping. `$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "33.xml",
    data: {},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
}
});`

Comment: As I said above, check the console for an error. Also check the network requests to see what the exact response text is.