# How to read a value from embedded XML (xmlns) element in HTML Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-namespaces

Example code:

```
<div id="xmlData">
  <script id="data" type="application/xml">
    <xml>
      <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema" table="ARTICLE" xmlns:s="0" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:dt="1">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
          <s:AttributeType name="ID">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="10" rs:maybenull="false" />
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:AttributeType name="NAME">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="30" />
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:extends type="rs:rowbase" />
        </s:ElementType>
      </s:Schema>
      <rs:data xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <z:row ID="0001" NAME="name 1" />
        <z:row ID="0002" NAME="name 2" />
      </rs:data>
    </xml>
  </script>
</div>
```

This xml is embedded data in my html page. I need to read some values from this xml. How can I read the value in <s:Schema> for id or table in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly didn't even know you could put XML in a script tag like this, but based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html), you can do it like so, traversing the XML with selectors just like you would an HTML document:

```js
var xmlString = document.getElementById('data').innerText;
var parser = new DOMParser();

var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml"); //can also use "application/xml"

var xmlSchema = xmlDoc.querySelector("Schema");

var schemaId = xmlSchema.getAttribute("id");
console.log(schemaId); // "RowsetSchema"

var schemaTable = xmlSchema.getAttribute("table");
console.log(schemaTable); // "ARTICLE"
```

```html
<div id="xmlData">
  <script id="data" type="application/xml">
    <xml>
      <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema" table="ARTICLE" xmlns:s="0" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:dt="1">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
          <s:AttributeType name="ID">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="10" rs:maybenull="false" />
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:AttributeType name="NAME">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="30" />
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:extends type="rs:rowbase" />
        </s:ElementType>
      </s:Schema>
      <rs:data xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <z:row ID="0001" NAME="name 1" />
        <z:row ID="0002" NAME="name 2" />
      </rs:data>
    </xml>
  </script>
</div>
```